# Creating dynamic sp for inserting and deleting records from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I am wanting to create a dynamic delete and insert stored procedure for my archiving task in SQL Server.

Here are the temp tables I created:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgbJ2.png)

The source table contains the table names where the records came from. Those records will be inserted in the tables listed in table 2 (the destination table names). Countdays table contains the days for the records I want to archive.

Here's my code below.

```
    DECLARE @i int
    DECLARE @destinationTbl NVARCHAR(2048)
    DECLARE @sourcetbl NVARCHAR(2048)
    DECLARE @cntdays INT
    DECLARE @monthAgo dateTime

    SET @i = 1
    SET @destinationTbl = (SELECT Destination FROM #Table2 ID = @i)
    SET @sourcetbl = (SELECT Source FROM #Table1 WHERE ID = @i)
    SET @cntdays = (SELECT CountDays FROM Table3 WHERE ID = @i)
    SET @monthAgo = DATEADD(month,-@cntdays, GETDATE())

    SELECT @arctable
    SELECT @sourcetable
    SELECT @cntdays

    -------ERROR PART----------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO @destinationTbl
    SELECT TOP 10 * fROM @sourcetbl Where Createdttm < @monthAgo
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

After running I keep getting error

> Must declare the scalar variable for @destinationTbl, @sourcetbl and "@monthAgo".

I'm still stuck in the inserting part. I have not yet created a script for Deleting the records. I think if someone can help me with the insert script, deleting will be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL isn't a scripting language; you can't use a variable to replace something that need to be a literal. The statement `INSERT INTO @destinationTbl` will try to `INSERT` values into the **table variable** `@destinationTbl` *not* the table that has the same name as the value in the scalar variable `@destinationTbl`.

When using dynamic SQL, you need to **safely** inject the values into the query and pass the other variables as parameters:

```
DECLARE @i int;
DECLARE @destinationTbl sysname; --Changed datatype, an object cannot have 2048 characters in its name
DECLARE @sourcetbl sysname; --Changed datatype, an object cannot have 2048 characters in its name
DECLARE @cntdays INT; --This isn't used, only SET, is it needed?
DECLARE @monthAgo datetime;

SET @i = 1;
SET @destinationTbl = (SELECT Destination FROM #Table2 ID = @i);
SET @sourcetbl = (SELECT Source FROM #Table1 WHERE ID = @i);
SET @cntdays = (SELECT CountDays FROM Table3 WHERE ID = @i);
SET @monthAgo = DATEADD(month,-@cntdays, GETDATE());

PRINT @arctable;
PRINT @sourcetable;
PRINT @cntdays;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@destinationTbl) + @CRLF + --Assumed schema
           N'FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@sourcetbl) + @CRLF + --Assumed schema
           N'WHERE Createdttm < @monthAgo;';

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend.
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@monthAgo datetime', @monthAgo;
```

Comment: Hi Larmu. Thanks for the additional knowlegdge. I already tested the code and it works. Thanks for the help.